# ValueError: save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object form - Create model with form obj as fk

Tags: django

I try to do the following

```
class CaseCreateView(BSModalCreateView):
template_name = 'orders/create_case_modal.html'
form_class = NewCaseModal
success_message = 'Success: Case was created.'
success_url = reverse_lazy('scan_to_cart')

def form_valid(self, form):
    case_num = random_string_generator()
    obj = form.save(commit=False)
    obj.user = self.request.user
    obj.case_number = case_num
    mess_obj = MessageEntry.objects.create(user=obj.user, message_fk=obj, mess_obj=obj.initial_memo)
    return super(CaseCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Which gives me the following error.

```
    ValueError: save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'message_fk'.
```

This is a bootstrap_modal_forms window where I save a form. I want to create an object with a FK field (message_fk) hooked to the form obj.

I can't save() the obj before assign it to the message_fk, because in that case the form saves twice. (don't know why)

I never worked with class based views before and can't find a way to do this properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to save the `obj`, beore you can link a `MessageEntry` to it. If your `oj` is not saved, it has no `pk` assigned to id, and hence linking another object to it, is not possible.

> I can't `save()` the obj before assign it to the `message_fk`, because in that case the form saves twice.

The reason that happens is because the `super(CaseCreateView, self).form_valid(form)` will save the form. But we do not need to call `super(CaseCreateView, self).form_valid(form)` here, we can do what the [**`FormMixin.form_valid`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.form_valid) does: redirect to [**`get_success_url()`** result [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_success_url):

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormMixin

class CaseCreateView(BSModalCreateView):
    template_name = 'orders/create_case_modal.html'
    form_class = NewCaseModal
    success_message = 'Success: Case was created.'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('scan_to_cart')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        case_num = random_string_generator()
        self.object = obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.user = self.request.user
        obj.case_number = case_num
        obj.save()
        mess_obj = MessageEntry.objects.create(user=obj.user, message_fk=obj, mess_obj=obj.initial_memo)
        return FormMixin.form_valid(self, form)
```

Comment: Thank you that seems to work! The only error this gives is -> in get_success_url
    url = self.success_url.format(**self.object.__dict__)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__dict__'

Comment: @sandermander: ah yes, you need to set `self.object`. Updated.

Comment: And now it saves twice again... hmmm

Comment: @sandermander: you did call it with `FormMixin.form_valid(self, form)`, *not* `ModelFormMixin` right?

Comment: @sandermander: as specified here, I don't see a trace where it will save http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/#form_valid

Comment: You did not make queries when obtaining the `get_absolute_url`, and/or `initial_memo` right?

Comment: I don't see the success message this is the terminal after creating a "case" [07/Sep/2019 14:51:38] "GET /admin/orders/ordercasemodel/ HTTP/1.1" 200 10408
[07/Sep/2019 14:51:38] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3185
[07/Sep/2019 14:51:42] "POST /admin/orders/ordercasemodel/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5441
[07/Sep/2019 14:51:43] "POST /admin/orders/ordercasemodel/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[07/Sep/2019 14:51:43] "GET /admin/orders/ordercasemodel/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3973
[07/Sep/2019 14:51:44] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3185
[07/Sep/2019 14:56:35] "GET /orders/create/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3261

Comment: @sandermander: well there will be two queries to construct objects of course: one to save the `obj`, and one to save the `MessageEntry`, unless your model is a `MessageEntry`, but in that case the `MessageEntry.objects.create(..)` should be removed. But as you can see in the source code (in the link provided), the other functions do not make any queries.

Comment: @sandermander: a POST usually has as response a redirect: this is the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) This was already discussed in the design of HTTP 1.0 Returning a 200 is a severe anti-pattern.